# How to use the {{ lhs == rhs, ineqs }, ... } form of Exclusions?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to make use of this option:

[image]

To plot the principal portion of `Tan`:

```
SetOptions[Plot, PlotRange -> {-2 Pi, 2 Pi}, AspectRatio -> 1];
f = Tan;

{Plot[InverseFunction[f]@x, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}],
 Plot[f@x, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, Exclusions -> {{x, x < -Pi/2, x >  Pi/2}}]}
```

But I am not getting what I expect:

[image]

I'm expecting to only see the principal period of the tangent curve.

I realize I could get the desired plot by changing the iterator in the second case to `{x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}`, but I actually want to show ticks for the larger `{-2 Pi, 2 Pi}` range.

It seems like this case is what the inqualities form of `Exclusions` would be meant for.  I have tried several variations of the above and can't find a form that works.

Comment: `-Pi/2 > x > Pi/2` - wait… how can a number be greater than a positive number but less than a negative one?

Comment: That's an error in how I transcribed my question, I'll correct in in a sec.  It should be `x < -Pi/2, x >  Pi/2`, which also does not work.

Comment: (sorry, was trying to do two things at once. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can use `RegionFunction`

```
{Plot[InverseFunction[f]@x, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}], 
 Plot[f@x, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Pi/2 > x > -Pi/2]]}
```

[image]

Comment: @billc You could also add `Exclusions -> {-Pi/2, Pi/2}` to get rid of the vertical asymptotes.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another possibility:

```
f = Tan;
{Plot[InverseFunction[f] @ x, {x, -2 π, 2 π}], 
 Plot[ConditionalExpression[f @ x, Abs[x] < π/2], {x, -2 π, 2 π},
      Exclusions -> {Cos[x] == 0}]} // GraphicsRow
```

Comment: This is a cool insight!  That said, I feel like I should leave @Algohi 's answer as the accepted one, since it addresses the MMA question more generally.  All of this still leaves unanswered how the inequality form of the `Exclusions` directive is supposed to work.  I can't find any examples anywhere.  :/

Comment: It's fine that Algohi's answer is the accepted one; I merely wanted to present an alternative. Note that `Piecewise[]` is also usable: `Piecewise[{{f @ x, Abs[x] < π/2}}, Indeterminate]`.